# setting up cluster on GCP with Cloudera Director

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloudera, cloudera-director

I'm following along with the [instructions on Cloudera's website](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/director/latest/topics/director_get_started_gcp_install_cm_cdh.html) to set up a cluster using Cloudera Director.  However, when I get to the step where I'm supposed to "Add an Environment," I'm presented with two issues.   First, the region I selected (us-east1-b) when configuring my Google Compute instance is not available for selection on the Cloudera Director software.  Second, there is no option for me to upload Client ID JSON Keys, as the documentation says we should be able to do.  I've attached a screenshot of what I'm looking at.  Any clues?

My Cloudera director software is reporting itself as version 2.1.1, and the docs I'm looking at are for version 2.1.x.  Am I somehow working with an older version of the software?  Or are the Cloudera docs not in line with the current version?  Can anyone else running Cloudera 2.1.1 confirm that they're seeing something similar or different?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a field to load the Client ID JSON keys in the "Advanced Options" section under General Information. Click the > to expand the Advanced Options.

You should be able to type in the region you want even if it isn't provided as a value in the drop-down.

Comment: I'v expanded the advanced options (shown in the screenshot), and the region field is a dropdown, not a text box.  Is it possible that I somehow don't have 2.1.1 installed, even though that's what it says if I click on the question mark in the upper right corner of the window?

Comment: I was wrong, the dropdown can be edited.   However, there is still no field to load the client ID JSON keys.   It only asks for SSH credentials as show in the screenshot.

Comment: Christ almighty I'm an idiot.  I didn't see the "Advanced Options" under General Information, only under "Google Compute Engine."